# Given $f(x)=x/(e^x-1),$ find the increasing and decreasing interval and sketch a graph

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I used limitation to prove that limit $x$ to $0$ $f(x)$ exists which is equal to $1,$ but I can't prove that whether $f(0)$ exist or not, I also found that limit $x$ to infinity $f(x)=0$ which $y=0$ is the horizontal asymptote and limit x to negative infinity $f(x)= \infty.$ Since I can't prove $f(0)$ exist or not, but when $f'(x)=0,$ I found that $x=0,$ $x=0$ is a critical point? I know the function is decreasing from negative infinity, but which interval should I write? (-infinity, infinity) or (-infinity,0)u(0,infinity)? or else?

Comment: For a start you can find out if $f(0)$ exists by L'Hospital Rule.

Comment: so when limiting x to 0 f(x) exists, then f(0) exist? or you mean directly using L'Hospital Rule on f(x)??

Comment: When applying LH, the numerator becomes $1$ and the denominator $e^x$ and so the limit is $1$. There is a hole in the graph at $(0,1)$. Now can you use the Quotient Rule to find the derivative?

Comment: yeah that what I wrote at the body, you said that (0,1) is a hole, I already found the derivative as I wrote at the body there, please see the body part when derivative =0, I find that x=0, so since you said (0,1) is a hole, do you mean that there is no critical point?

Comment: This graph has no critical values and it is decreasing on its entire domain

Comment: ok thank you so much